# Cannot override Material UI Typography fontWeight

Tags: material-ui

I just started using Material UI and learning to customize the default theme. I tried changing default palette color and it worked but overriding the typography property was not working.

I am trying to fontWeight property of h3 variant. The default fontWeight for h3 variant is 400. I am changing it to 100 or 300 but it's not reflecting.

Here is my code

**Component.js**

```
return (

         <Typography variant="h3" color="secondary">
               Arc Development
         </Typography>
    )
```

**theme.js**

```
import {createMuiTheme} from "@material-ui/core";

const arcBlue = "#0B72B9";
const arcOrange = "#FFBA60";

export default createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        common: {
            blue: `${arcBlue}`,
            orange: `${arcOrange}`,
        },
        primary: {
            main: `${arcBlue}`
        },
        secondary: {
            main: `${arcOrange}`
        }
    },
    typography: {
        h3: {
            fontS: 0,
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao, to override `Typography` you have to define in  your theme an object called `overrides` and then inside this object you have to define another object called `MuiTypography` and override the `h3` variant like this:

```
export default createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        common: {
            blue: `${arcBlue}`,
            orange: `${arcOrange}`,
        },
        primary: {
            main: `${arcBlue}`
        },
        secondary: {
            main: `${arcOrange}`
        }
    },
    overrides: {
       MuiTypography: {
          h3: {
           fontWeight: 100
       }
    }
  }
});
```

And if you inspect the element, you will see:

[image]

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-textfield-forked-cntvz?file=/src/index.js) a codesandbox example.

Comment: I used your code but its still not working not even your codesandbox example

Comment: @FahadShaikh I updated my answer with a proof that my example works. Please, see my example in all details... have you created a theme used `const theme = createMuiTheme(Theme);`? Have you wrapped your component inside a `ThemeProvider ` passing `theme` like `<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>`? Your code example is not completed and I can't provide more suggestions. Do you have a codesandbox example so we can work on the same code?

Comment: I created my own codesandbox  and and inspected it developer tools. I found that the code is working (obviously your's too) but font weight is not being changed of the text.

[my codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-wright-rkn6o?file=/src/theme.js)

Comment: @FahadShaikh yes I don't see graphical differences under 400. I see differences on values 600 and 800. After 800 I can't see differences.